# iOS application patch download from App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there any way to download iOS apps by patches from App Store. 
One of my current application holds size of 60 MB .So when ever there is an update  user has to download app again completely , instead is there option where user can download only patch.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, the entire bundle is re-downloaded. There are no patches in the iOS App Store.

Edit: It seems like Apple automatically generates optimized update packages: [Reducing Download Size for iOS App Updates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1779/_index.html)